# GCC 2.95.3: compilation error with backslash and CRLF line terminators

Tags: c, gcc, newline

I have an **Ubuntu 17.04** virtual machine. On this OS, that is shipped with GCC 6.x, I installed GCC **4.9** from official repository, then I compiled:

- GCC **4.7.0** from **GCC 4.9**
- GCC **3.0.4** from GCC **4.7.0**
- GCC **2.95.3** from GCC **3.0.4**

Now, when I build an old C code I receive this error on a multiline macro:

```
stray '\' in program
```

I wrote a Python script for automatically change the line terminators from Windows one (CRLF) to Linux one. In this way the code is compiled fine.

Is there a way for GCC 2.95.3 to correctly understand the code without changes? AFAIK GCC must understands well the difference

Comment: Why would you use such an old version of gcc? Can you post the code which it complained about? If possible try to preserve CR and LF if present in the source.

Comment: "_without changes_" - Semi-useful: Add a `make` rule to "compile" `.cpp` code to `.cppux`: `%.cpp : %.cppux` and in that use `dos2unix` to compile it. From there, it should be a breeze. It's the same as your [tag:python] script, but it usually exists on target systems already.

Comment: I'm going to assume that this old code did compile way back when. So how did it change since then? Could it be a SCM that added the newlines when you got the code back out? Perhaps it could be configured to not add them, or remove them (such as can be done with [git](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings)

Comment: @Lundin I'm trying to use such an old version of GCC because I have a code with a 32 bit dynamic recompilator inside it. The original binary built from the original source code works without problem on a new 64 bit machine but the source code built with a newer compilator doens't work. So I'm tryng to understand why this problem occurs. There's something "wrong" with new compilator. With "wrong" I mean that the original source code was written with the available compilator in mind

Comment: @Francesco have you just tried compiling with newer GCC but in 32 bit mode? I.e. `-m32` switch?

Comment: @alagner yes, without success. I don't understand. Inside dynamic recompilator there is a custom logger, executing the binary (built on 64 bit machine) I received "Unimplemented op 7C007C00 (1F,00)". So the developer says that the machine code pointed by function pointer is not recognizable by the dynarec. But... The original binary works on 64 bit cpu, so the underlying assembly code generated by the dynarec emitter is a valid x86_64 machine code. I can't understand where is the problem. I tried with gcc 3.0 without luck. Any idea?

Comment: @Francesco lots of possibilites there, starting from what you think, i.e. relying on some compiler-bug or similar, up to dynamic recompiler not supporting some opcodes. Is this dynamic thing also GCC-based? Is it supposed to support modern architectures? Maybe you need i386-targeted gcc?

Comment: @alagner with gcc 3.0 is implicit the i386 target, isn't it? I'm not an expert of compilers, could you please point me on the right direction? At the moment I have an Ubuntu 32 bit virtual machine (on 64 bit system) with gcc 3.0 fully operational. Maybe I have to build gcc 3.0 in a different way (some options to pass to ./configure?)

Comment: @Francesco hard to say really, you can try calling gcc with `-print-multiarch` but I can't tell if that switch is supported on such old versions. What does calling `file your_binary` state in case of all the binaries you've been trying to use this far?

Comment: @alagner that parameter is not supported, binary build with gcc 3.0 shows this: `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped`

Comment: @Francesco I'm guessing it's the same for the original build, or...?

Comment: @alagner the original build is a `PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows, UPX compressed` but I tried to build the binary on Windows with the same exact results (same error log) as Linux. Also the original binary was compiled using gcc (I supposed mingw). Thanks for your time

Comment: @Francesco I guess you've missed the part about cross-compiilation ;) What you need is linux mingw build (basically GCC running on linux capable on building for Windows). I know Debian used to ship those packages several years ago, not sure about nowadays though.

Comment: @alagner as I said before the code is portable, I already tried to compile on Windows with mingw with the exact same result as gcc build on Ubuntu

Comment: @Francesco it might be portable in terms of building on various platforms, but the recompiler module (whatever that is) does not have/seem to be. Can you present a broader picture?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240349/discussion-between-francesco-and-alagner).

Comment: It's not the specific version of GCC that prevents compiling because of the line terminators. Any compiler I used does not accept CR LF after a backslash if it expects just LF. -- I would not try to compile with such an old compiler. Instead I would look for the bug or problem and repair the source code.

Comment: @thebusybee there isn't a bug in the code. I removed all CRLF with my Python script and the code compiles fine without any errors

Comment: You said in a comment "_but the source code built with a newer compilator doens't work_". So, how are we suppose to interpret this?

Comment: @thebusybee read all the comments. Doesn't work **as expected**, but the logic is preserved. The dynarec advices on unknown OpCode. If it founds something that doesn't known (it can't emit machine code for that) it exits. But the same code built on x86 32 bit machine in 2003 works on current x86 and x86_64 machines. So why we have to think that the code has a bug? Maybe the problem is the changes during 20 years on how the compiler assembles the executable. Do you know how a dynarec works? I'm writing the dynarec for ARM, I don't have the time to re-think the original x86 dynarec

Comment: If a program works differently when compiled by different compilers or for different targets, it's commonly non-portability or undefined behavior. Anyway, we can consider this a bug. However, it's your project and so your choice. ;-) -- The core issue is not the version of GCC but the line terminators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all CRLF with my Python script and the code compiles fine without any errors